# How can I use putObject to upload a csv file to AWS S3 from Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I tried to directly upload the file stream as a parameter, but it didn't work.

```
var param = {
    Bucket: 'sql-dev',
    Key: 'Report',
    Body: new Buffer(fs.createWriteStream('./temp/ALL.csv'))
};  
s3bucket.putObject(param, function(err, data){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(data);
});
```

How do I use that?

Comment: Define "didn't work."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a read stream, not a write stream. Also, you shouldn't be wrapping your stream inside a Buffer.

```
var param = {
    Bucket: 'sql-dev',
    Key: 'Report',
    Body: fs.createReadStream('./temp/ALL.csv')
};  
s3bucket.putObject(param, function(err, data){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: You should be right, I just used 'readFile' that was working.

Comment: I have issue on uploading csv file. when i tried using .txt it works but when i tried .csv it returns me an error